# About tomcat-jdbc comapatibility with Java version

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

I have two questions about Tomcat JDBC:

1. What does the "M" abbreviation in "tomcat 9.0.0.M21" (or other versions) mean?
2. In Tomcat JDBC what is the Java version compatibility?

With Regards,

Comment: `M` means Milestone.

Answer (score 2):

1. `M` stands for [*milestone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milestone_(project_management)). Milestone releases are iterations of software releases between minor or major releases. So `9.0.0.M21` is the 21st milestone release for the `9.0.0` branch. There may be more milestones before `9.0.0` is finalized.
2. This [page](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) lists the supported Java versions for each Tomcat release.